How to repair the bricks on an uneven undercut chimney
I used an angle grinder since I could not find a rental place with an undercut saw and botched the top (angled down instead of flat). The fact that the brick is painted makes the mistake pop out even more.
What is a good way to add filler to the brick/mortar portion?
I was thinking if using filler and placing wax paper on the temporary planks so the filler could be supported underneath.
I plan to touch up paint after and not worry about it flashing slightly different.
Hindsight, I would have tried to find a used undercut or bought one new. And the gas insert allows for zero clearance hearth.



I would caulk that in with a caulk that is supplied by the tile grout makers. It is available in different colors, come in a sanded finish to match the texture of the brick joints and in many cases is water based, so the excess is easily cleaned.
One note of caution, I thought all of this type of caulk was water based, no they aren't, I learned the hard way. The fix was simple enough. Instead of using water and a tile sponge to profile the joint, I used paint thinner instead.

Good advice jack. I ended up using the non-sag variety after scuffing up the edges. I used saran wrap with a little bit of mineral oil so it wouldn't stick to the floor. It worked well and painted it looked good. If course I always see my slight imperfections.

I like Jack's approach, but you might just clean up the edge to make it more uniform and brick-like, then ignore it. There's no rule that says your brick has to grow out of your flooring. My stone fireplace shows a gap after my flooring project and it's not an issue.
Bring your angle grinder back out and bevel the edge slightly, creating a straighter, slightly rounded (but still imperfect) edge. Remove all the visible mortar along the bottom to leave clean brick.
Paint to match and move on with life.

Sorry just read this now a long time later. I doubt my grinding skills, as I would have to remove the guard to do it.  The painting did the most to hide any perfections than anything else.  Someone once told me the enemy of good is perfect, and they are right.
